# javascript alert box cannot popup in Eclipse when running tomcat

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat, localhost, alert

The alert is written as script in html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("test");
      });
</script>
```

When opening the file in *browser*, alert box prompts as desired.
However, when I tried to run on localhost:8080 **with TomCat inside Eclipse**, it does not pop any alert box anymore.

I have checked Eclipse preference, under WebService->Popup Dialogue, it does not hide any pop-ups. 
Does anyone know if the setting is hidden somewhere or I am doing something else wrong? Thank you!

Comment: have you checked whether you are returning correct html or jsp from servlet ?

Comment: how do i check that? but it turns out my eclipse is not showing other things other than just alert box, it also has problem display some images when browsing..

Comment: can you share your directory structure of web project may be a snapshot ? it sometime happens that the path of resources as like .js file or images provided in html or jsp is not being fulfilled correctly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case might be your alert box is blocked by popup blocker. Just check whether you have installed and activated any of popup blocker.
Another case may be that resource path is not fulfilled properly. Just check whether your **.js lib** and images are present in proper directory.
have a look on directory structure below ( it worked for me and even I faced the same problem once :) )

[image]

Comment: Thank you for following up, I dont have enough reputation to upload photos, below is the link to the snapshot of my directory structure. It looks similar to yours @A.man http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8560/8991431325_12d150f5f2_o.png

Also, I realized that my eclipse pops alert box after i refresh the url. So I think the settings are actually fine, but this other problem arises(i.e must refresh every time), any ideas why?

Comment: **eclipse pops alert box**, I actually did not get this. have you setup any breakpoint on your java code and started tomcat in debug mode ? If so try to remove breakpoint or run project on tomcat without debug mode.

Comment: Hi, eclipse is supposed to pop the alert("something"); written in javascript. Turns out it is other part of the code the prevent it from showing, not the setting of Eclipse. Thank you very much Aman!I had a good experience of posting my first question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the jquery.js file is in the same folder where you have html file and make sure you have imported the same .js file in the html file.